# Combining two different arrays using pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function and inside it, I have two arrays and two loops.
First one is an array of characters and the second one is an array of pointers with NULL values. In the first loop, I set values to null.

```
void printName(char *pointer, int size)
{
    char arrayOfChars[10] = "test";
    char *arrayOfPointers[10]

    // set values to null
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfPointers; i++)
    {
         arrayOfPointers[i] = NULL;
    }
    int j = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Value: %d: %p\n",arrayOfChars[j], arrayOfPointers+j);
        j++;
    }
    while(j < 10);
}
```

so what I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
value: t : 0028FEF
value: e : 0028FEY
value: s : 0028FEX
value: t : 0028FEE
```

Comment: Your introduction is wrong, since your first loop actually just sets the pointers to null. But what is your question?

Comment: This can't possibly work: `for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfPointers; i++)`, it must be `i < 10` or similar.

Comment: Your imagenary system is drunk to print out X and Y for address values

Comment: Sorry I modified my question to make more sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do what I think you want, rather than what I think you're asking for:

```
void printName(char *pointer, int size)
{
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("Value: %d, addr: %p\n", pointer[i], pointer + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     arrayOfPointers[i] = &arrayOfChars[i];
}
```

followed  by:

```
int j = 0;
do
{
    printf("Value: %d: %p\n",arrayOfChars[j], arrayOfPointers[j]);
    j++;
}
while(j < 10);
```